# Can a invulnerable file be accessed and edited in windows?

Tags: windows

In windows there are some files which are invulnerable,like the file which contains the password of the users.Can such file be opened while working on the same OS?
On the other hand,if I try to open those files after installing another OS will it open?

Comment: The short story, nothing is invulnerable to knowledgeable people. you might edit your question to include what you are trying to do or what you suspect is being done. Your question is sort of vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it inside windows without any weird hack.

But you sure can do it (without even having to install a new OS), just boot the PC from a linux boot cd, by doing so, you take the control out of windows.

If you're looking for the SAM file these links will help:

- [SAM Files and NT Password Hashes](http://www.hackinthebox.org/modules.php?op=modload&name=News&file=article&sid=5721&mode=thread&order=0&thold=0)
- [SAM File Location](http://www.realgeek.com/forums/sam-file-location-91130.html)

LINUX LIVE CD: (just record it with any CD burner that can record an ISO):

- [The Live CD List](http://www.livecdlist.com/)
  (the list is huge, I would just pick Ubuntu).